# Syntax Error: Undefined Label: 'LABELNAME'

Tags: assembly, syntax-error, motorola, microprocessors, 6800

I am getting:

> `Syntax Error: Undefined Label: 'LABELNAME'`

when trying to compile the code with the [this](https://www.hvrsoftware.com/6800IDE.zip) (assembler 6800IDE from https://www.hvrsoftware.com/6800emu.htm):

```
    BRA LABELNAME
LABELNAME: LDAA #0
```

Comment: I'd suggest including the name of the assembler in the question itself (not just the link URL) so searches that include that as a keyword will still find this.  That's an odd design; in most assemblers `:` after a label name is recommended to disambiguate vs. mnemonics!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label definitions are *not* supposed to contain `:`. So replace:

```
LABELNAME: LDAA #0
```

with:

```
LABELNAME LDAA #0
```

to have:

```
    BRA LABELNAME
LABELNAME LDAA #0
```